# Marquee not flowing from end of screen to the other

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

How do I update MarqueeBanner so that my text flows from one end of the screen to the other, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/XxUXD/ using TailwindCSS?

**MarqueeBanner.tsx**

```
import { XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';

export default function MarqueeBanner() {
  return (
    <div className="relative flex gap-x-6 bg-[#B8A78D] py-2 px-6 sm:px-3.5 sm:before:flex-1 font-helveticaNeueLight">
      <p className="text-sm leading-6 text-white animate-marquee whitespace-nowrap">
        <a href="#"><span className="font-bold">Just In:</span> We’re closed for holidays from December 20th 2021 to Jan 9th 2022</a>
      </p>
      <div className="flex flex-1 justify-end">
        <button type="button" className="-m-3 p-3 focus-visible:outline-offset-[-4px]">
          <span className="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
          <XMarkIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-white" aria-hidden="true" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**tailwindc.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    './next.config.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        blairItcMedium: 'Blair ITC Medium, sans-serif',
        helveticaNeueLight: 'Helvetica Neue Light, sans-serif',
      },
      animation: {
        marquee: 'marquee 5s linear infinite',
      },
      keyframes: {
        marquee: {
          '0%': { transform: 'translateX(0%)' },
          '100%': { transform: 'translateX(-100%)' },
        },
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography'), require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your animation to go from edge to edge of the container, then you need to set the from value in your animation to `translateX(100%)`. Setting the initial value to `translateX(0%)`, is like saying start from your normal position.  I also removed to flex on the container.

[Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/m7HA6aPvfT?file=config)

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        blairItcMedium: 'Blair ITC Medium, sans-serif',
        helveticaNeueLight: 'Helvetica Neue Light, sans-serif',
      },
      animation: {
        marquee: 'marquee 25s linear infinite',
      },
      keyframes: {
        marquee: {
          '0%': { transform: 'translateX(100%)' },
          '100%': { transform: 'translateX(-100%)' },
        },
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/typography'), require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
}
```

JSX:

```
import { XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid';

export default function MarqueeBanner() {
  return (
    <div className="font-helveticaNeueLight relative gap-x-6 bg-[#B8A78D] py-2 px-6 sm:px-3.5 sm:before:flex-1">
      <p className="animate-marquee whitespace-nowrap text-sm leading-6 text-white">
        <a href="#"><span className="font-bold">Just In:</span> We’re closed for holidays from December 20th 2021 to Jan 9th 2022</a>
      </p>
      <div className="absolute right-0 top-0 bottom-0 px-2 flex bg-[#B8A78D]">
        <button type="button" className="-m-3 p-3 focus-visible:outline-offset-[-4px]">
          <span className="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
          <XMarkIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-white" aria-hidden="true" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```